# Reverse DNS Lookup in Delphi 12?

Tags: delphi, dns, reverse-dns, delphi-12-athens

With ICS (Overbyte Internet Component Suite), I tried to do a ***Reverse DNS Lookup***, i.e. retrieve the domain name associated with an IP address.

I loaded the sample project `OverByteIcsDnsResolver.dpr` in Delphi 12. However, that project does a normal DNS lookup (domain -> IP address).

But I need the opposite: IP address -> domain name.

Can anyone show me how to do that in Delphi 12?

Example: When I do a normal DNS lookup for `overbyte.eu`, I get `91.183.89.111`.

How to get `overbyte.eu` from `91.183.89.111`?

Comment: Please show the code you are actually using, don't assume people have (or are willing to download) other people's sample code. In any case, have you looked at ICS's  `TIcsDomainNameCache`/`TIcsDomNameCacheHttps` components yet? "*Added new components TIcsDomainNameCache and TIcsDomNameCacheHttps designed to simplify forward domain name and reverse IP address lookup in applications*". Or, have you considered simply using your platform's `getnameinfo()` API and let the OS handle the lookup for you?